# What is the name for confusables of similar meanings?

Tags: confusables

In researching confusables, I have yet to come across a term that describes the type of confusable that is created by two words of similar meaning but different spelling and pronunciation. The term synonyms is defined as being words of the *same* meaning, but do they also apply to words of similar or related meaning? For example, less/fewer or imply/infer.

PS - Confusables is often referred to as an informal term. Does a form term exist for the concept?

Comment: While *less* and *fewer* (like *farther* and *further*) can be said to have similar meanings (for different applications), *imply* and *infer* (like *emigrate* and *immigrate*) are opposites. Yes, they are related, but they aren't similar in meaning. They are not near synonyms at all. So, I think you're going to have a hard time finding a word that covers all of the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Words which learners (and also native speakers) get confused by are simply called "**confusing verbs**". There may be a linguistic, more technical term that describes this aspect but I'm not aware of one.

**Confusing words**–or **verbs**–are notorious for even tripping up native speakers

For example

- ***advise*** (verb) **vs** ***advice*** (noun)
  ["Advise" vs. "advice"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/)
- ***effect* vs *affect***
  ["Effect" vs. "Affect"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315/)
- ***bring* vs *take***
  ["Bring" versus "take"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5231/)
- ***borrow* vs *lend***
  [Word to describes the money that you lend to somebody?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/442641/)
- ***compliment* vs *complement***
  i) [Mnemonic for "complement / compliment"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130167/)
  ii)["Complimentary" vs "complementary"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14963/)
- ***lay* vs *lie***
  [What is the difference between "lay" and "lie"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105/)
- ***do* vs *make* vs *take***
  admittedly in this instance knowing which verb to use is more confusing for non-native than native speakers.
  i) [What is the difference between the verbs "make and "do"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16441/)
  ii) [What is the difference between 'make an experiment' and 'do an experiment'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128742/)
  iii) [What is the difference between 'make decision' and 'take decision'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6431/)
  iv) [Make/take a photograph?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114456/)
- ***practice* vs *practise***
  i) ["Practise" vs. "practice"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9883/)
  ii) [Can Practice (verb) and Practise (verb) indicate two different meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/573314/)
- ***rise* vs *raise***
  i) [What is the difference between "raise" and "rise"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/)
  ii) ["Pay rise" vs "pay raise"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15105/)
- ***say* vs *tell***
  ["Told" vs. "said to" somebody](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48734/)

Other types of confusing words are **[homophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone)** which are two or more words whose meanings and spellings are different but are  pronounced in the same way. Examples:

- ***ate*** vs ***eight***
- ***led*** vs ***lead*** (the metal)
- ***site*** vs ***sight***
- ***flower*** vs ***flour***
- ***they're*** vs ***their*** vs ***there***
- ***to*** vs ***too*** vs ***two***

Words that have the same spelling and pronunciation but different meanings are called **homonyms**

e.g
*the tree's* ***bark*** (outer layer) vs *most dogs* ***bark*** (sound)

*The ***stalk*** of a plant* (part of a plant) vs *to ***stalk*** someone* (verb)

*Waiter there's **a *fly*** in my soup* (the insect) vs *Come ***fly*** away with me* (verb)

Comment: ... less / fewer? between / among?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can't possibly list them all, these are the ones (mostly verbs) that came into my nod. But thanks for the downvote? because...? I was attempting to be  helpful to the community by providing a good list of EL&U questions?

Comment: If you wish to do so, you could ask a question clear enough for ELU to make the answer a wel targetted one, answering it yourself. Though lists are still eschewed on ELU.  As Tinfoil hat comments above, OP isn't clear about what he's asking here.

Comment: Earth, land, ground, dirt,

Comment: OP inquires about "two words of similar [not synonomous] meaning but different spelling and pronunciation." How does your answer adress this? For example, *ate* and *eight* have no similarity in meaning and they don't have different pronunciations. *Bark* and *bark* have no similarity in meaning and they have the same spelling and pronunciation. *Borrow* and *lend* are not similar in meaning — they are "related" but opposite, and so on.

Comment: @TinfoilHat   I thought it was interesting to expand and include other examples of confusing words = confusables. But the examples I cite at the beginning: *advice* / *advise*, *effect* / *affect*, and *rise* / *raise* do match the OP's description.

Answer (score 3):

The term *[confusables](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-confusables-words-1689908)* includes words with similar but non-identical meanings like *imply/infer* and *less/fewer*. A term that applies principally to similar or related meanings is

**near-synonym**

> (linguistics) A term whose meaning is similar, but not identical, to
> that of another term. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/near-synonym)

> A word that has almost the same meaning as another word:
>
> The words
> "hungry" and "peckish" are near-synonyms.
>
> Near synonyms are more
> common than perfect synonyms.
>
> **Near-synonyms may be
> regarded as equivalent for some purposes, but not others.**  [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/near-synonym)

---

> **case**. This multifaceted word is often a sign of verbal inflation, especially in its uses as a **near-synonym** of *situation*.
> ...
> **include; comprise.** The basic difference between these **near-synonyms** is that *include* implies nonexclusivity..., while *comprise* implies exclusivity... [Garner; *The Chicago Guide to Grammar, Usage and Punctuation*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Chicago_Guide_to_Grammar_Usage_and_P/5jPnDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=The%20Chicago%20Guide%20to%20Grammar,%20Usage%20and%20Punctuation%20%22the%20basic%20difference%20between%20these%22&pg=PT290&printsec=frontcover)

> **A list of commonly used near-synonyms**
>
> Here are some examples of commonly used **near-synonyms** for legal
> concepts used in legal documents. There are subtle differences in
> meaning or usage between them.
>
> Assign...transfer
> Breach...infringement
> Clause...article
> Contract...agreement
> ... [Rupert Haigh; *Legal English*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Legal_English/NALrBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22legal%20english%22%20near%20synonyms&pg=PA81&printsec=frontcover) p.81

---

**confusable** (noun)

> Two or more words or ideas that can easily be confused
>
> *confusables such as ‘principle’ and ‘principal’* [Oxford Advanced Learner's](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/confusable_2?q=confusables)

(The above definition of the singular as "two or more ..." bothers me.)

> A word or phrase that is easily confused with another in meaning or
> usage such as *mitigate* which is often confused with *militate.* *New
> Oxford American Dictionary*

> A word or phrase that is easily confused with another [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/confusable)

(I do not see the noun in the OED.)

---

A related term is **partial synonym**

See [What is the difference between partial and total synonyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94972/what-is-the-difference-between-partial-and-total-synonyms/95137)

> Synonymy, as we have seen, is defined where two lexemes are mutually
> hyponymous, in other words where their extensions (and senses) are
> required to be identical, as shown in (61)
> ....
> Unfortunately this
> definition does not allow for **partial synonymy**, since extensions
> in the theory are discrete, i.e. there are no fuzzy edges where, for
> example there may be things that are almost pullovers but that are not
> a sweater.  Since, as we have noted, full synonymy is rarely, if ever,
> attested, this makes the definition in (61) less useful than it might
> be. Ronnie Cann; *Formal Semantics,* p. 220

Comment: Thanks for help with those terms! Very helpful!